# The ng-select angular library i am using uses enter key to select a option i need it on tab out

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

i don't have the option of using other ng-select angular library already there are multiple other dependencies for using this library.I need to customize or do something please i need your help on this guys library i am using  link https://github.com/basvandenberg/ng-select

```
 <ng-select></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have forked this library and incorporated tab for option selection https://github.com/ManojRamanan/ng-select my issue is resolved